# getting promise instead of value in laravel vue js

Tags: vue.js, promise

I am getting promise instead of value.
calling getPlayerInfo from blade
`@{{getPlayerInfo(bats.batsman_id)}}`

```
<script>
var app = new Vue({
      el: '#carcontainer',
      data: {
          errors: [],
      },
      methods: {
        getPlayerInfo:(id)=>{
            return axios.get(matchapi+'players/'+id+'/stats'+token)
            .then(res=>res.data.response.player.title);
            //return id;
        }
      },
    });

    </script>
```